# Correct way of checking a directory is available for writing

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, directory, file-access

I recently added the use of [GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the application.  During code review it was highlighted that the description of GetTempPath contains the information:

> The application should verify the existence of the path and adequate access rights to the path prior to any use for file I/O operations.

Now all file access is wrapped in try/catch blocks and what system will there be that doesn't have access to it's own temp directory?

My initial idea would be to attempt creating the directories if they don't exist (via GetFileAttributes and CreateDirectory) and then to create a file, write a byte and then delete the file. While that will work it smacks of ignorance - surely there is a better way of checking that you have write access to a folder?

I started looking and found File Attribute Constants, Generic Access Rights, Standard Access Rights, File Access Rights Constants and GetSecurityInfo function. All of which seemed to create a solution that is longer than the create a file and see if it sticks method.

**So what is the correct way using WinAPI functions of checking you have write access to a folder?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MSDN note is misleading.  You might want to check to see if the path returned exists (and if not, create it), but the only way to know if you can write there is to write there.

Furthermore, just because you can write there now doesn't mean you can write there later.  The user or other programs may delete things, change security settings, lock directories, etc.  Trying to validate ahead of time that it's a place you can write is a waste of time.  Just write when you need to, and be prepared for failure.

Comment: Especially as the game changes when AV products get involved. They are well known for blocking some operations in the temp folder in the name of security, e.g. blocking executables.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to attempt to write files to the directory. If writing fails due to lack of rights, then the error code will tell you that.  Look for [`ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx).

If you try and do it any other way then you will just be replicating system code that was about to run anyway. And there's little chance for you to replicate it perfectly for current versions of Windows and future versions.

There's no need to create a file and write a single byte to it. Just assume that you have write access to the temporary folder and attempt to write the entire file(s) that you need to. If you ever encounter a failure then you may as well terminate the process. There's not much point in proceeding if you can't write to the temporary folder.

Comment: Well I will be replicating code that is going to happen anyway by writing file and seeing if I get an access denied message. I want to test if the directory exists and is writable and if not I can fall back to a default directory.

Comment: Don't bother. That section of the MSDN docs just means that the GetTempPath API won't create the directory for you. It's doesn't mean that it is normal or reasonable for it not to exist. Just assume that the temp folder is there and write to it. If it fails report an error to the user and give up. Consider having a working temp folder a pre-requisite of your software. Or think of it like this, what if your "default directory" is not available? Will you have a fall back for that? You have to draw the line somewhere.

Comment: I have the same problem. At some point I need to know if I have write access to some directory. Right now I have a solution that works (create a file with random name in that directory, check if creation was successful and the delete the file). The only problem occurs if the directory is write only, then the file created just before cannot be deleted.